# How can I add new existing property to my control?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, properties, controls

I have my own control:

```
public class newControl : Control
{
}
```

There is a `Text` property, but there is not a `TextAlign` property. For example, I need this property similar to the `TextAlign` property of a `Button`, but I don't want inherit it from a button class.

So can I inherit only `TextAlign` property? If yes, how?

Comment: would inheriting from ButtonBase class help you or you dont want that also..otherwise you would need to create your own public property for your newControl..

Comment: Problem is that I don't want to have a lot of unusable properties and so on. I saw `ButtonBase` class of course, and it is not suitable for me. I need `TextAlign` property (with correct visual work) in my control, but I don't need border style (for example) there and so on... Question is _how to do, if it is possible_. Or I need to find anything else already contained all what I need. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just add it.  The built in enumeration is called `ContentAlignment`:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class newControl : Control {

  private ContentAlignment _TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

  [Description("The alignment of the text that will be displayed on the control.")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(ContentAlignment), "MiddleCenter")]
  public ContentAlignment TextAlign {
    get { return _TextAlign; }
    set { _TextAlign = value; }
  }
}
```

What you do with this property is up to you now.

Note that I added some attributes for how the control is used in the `PropertyGrid`.  The `DefaultValue` attribute does not *set* the value of the property, it just determines whether or not the property is displayed in bold or not.

To display the text using your `TextAlign` property, you would have to override the `OnPaint` method and draw it:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  switch (_TextAlign) {
    case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter: {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, this.ClientRectangle, this.ForeColor, Color.Empty, 
                              TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        break;
      }
    case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft: {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, this.ClientRectangle, this.ForeColor, Color.Empty,
                              TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        break;
      }
    // more case statements here for all alignments, etc.

  }
  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good! But do you know how to put Text on it exact this property? May be it is a little bit stupid question, but i don't see Text in my Control... How to get this property work like in button? P.S. `.Text` != "";

Comment: @justAuser Not sure I follow.  Do you mean that `this.Text` doesn't appear on the control when you put your control on a form?

Comment: @justAuser I added code to show the `OnPaint` override.  Since this it *your* custom control, you will have to do the work of painting what you want displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it is what i'm looking for! Now I understand how it works.) Text doesn' appear when i put `this.Text = "something";`, I thinking it must to appear on the control) So may be it override on another class...

Answer (score 0):

First, consider inheriting from [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx), which has more properties that correspond to styling, such as `CssClass` and `Attributes`.

Rather than using the `TextAlign` property, I would recommend simply adding a CSS class to your page, and use set `CssClass` property, which is on the base class `WebControl`.

Alternatively, you could set the text alignment by doing the following (but a CSS class would be cleaner):

```
this.Attributes["style"] = "text-align: center";
```

Of course, you could always add your own property that writes the correct CSS to the `Attributes` collection as well.

Comment: But I use WinForms... I do not think that it is suitable. I'd like to have control only with what I need, nothing more. I can inherit `Form` with many good properties, but I don't need many of them...

Comment: Oh, I've tagged this question with `winforms` then. I assumed this was on the web.